# Does camel jetty-activemq create new activemq connection for each message

Tags: java, jetty, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have defined a camel jetty-activemq route as below:

from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8087/url1").to("activemq:queue:queue1)

Does camel create an activemq connection and then use that connection for all messages received by jetty or create an activemq connection per message.

I am planning to use a pooled connection for activemq, since my message inflow is pretty high per second, i need to understand camel behaviour to define the max connection pool size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveMQ component, as well as the JMS component, is based on JMSTemplate from Spring Framework, when sending messages.

As you fear, it creates and closes a connection+session+producer per message, which is not optimal performence wise.

As recommended in the [activemq component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/activemq#ActiveMQ-Usingconnectionpooling), you should set it up with pooling. Then you will reuse the connection/session/producer.

You could actually live with just one connection in the pool for that pool if you intend to use it for this route only.

ActiveMQ has made a [summary of tips and tricks](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html) with JMSTemplate. It's worth reading.

Update: Regarding the number of Connections related to concurrency:

Simplified, a Connection is a network connection ("socket") with the broker, that is shared among many threads. Each of your threads would still have it's own (pooled) session that uses the shared connection and operate concurrently. Multiple connection could still be an enhancement, if you have multiple ActiveMQ brokers and want to loadbalance between them (given ActiveMQ is the bottleneck and not your application).

```
failover:(ssl://host1:61616,ssl://host2:61616)
```

It might also be that, in practice, performance might go up to some small extent by using a limited set of connections instead of one, but that you probably have to test out for your particular environment.

Comment: Thanks Petter. That helps to understand. Why do you say "could actually live with just one connection". Sounds only one thread connecting to activemq. That would be a bottle neck. Doesn't the minThreads and maxThreads on jetty endpoint help crate multiple connections to broker from the activemq pool. Please comment.

Comment: Added an update to explain. You should see Session as the primary "per thread" object, not connection.